# python: x is not this or this operator

Tags: python, for-loop, operators, conditional-statements

is there a one liner for this?

```
for file_name in listoffiles:
    if file_name != 'meta':
        if file_name != 'results':
            #this do this
```

I tried this but it didn't do what I expected:

```
for file_name in listoffiles:
    if (file_name != 'meta') or (file_name  != 'results'):
        #this do this
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean operators:

```
if file_name != 'meta' and file_name != 'results':
```

Note that you should use **and** here, *both* conditions must be true!

Or use a (negative) membership test:

```
if file_name not in ('meta', 'results'):
```

If you are using Python 3, and especially if you need to test for more options, use a set:

```
if file_name not in {'meta', 'results'}:
```

Python 3 recognises the set literal and will store it with the code as a `frozenset()` constant object, making the test super-efficient.

Comment: Ahhh that's where I went wrong, should've used "and" not "or"! thanks Martijn.

Answer (score 1):

Try `not in`, stores all files in a `tuple` then check it. 
(as per Martijn Pieters)

```
for file_name in listoffiles:
    if file_name not in  ('meta', 'results'):
        # do something here
```

Comment: Don't use a list; CPython will automatically use a tuple here instead (immutables can be made into constants) but you shouldn't really count on that.